# Firefox Developer Tools - Can't catch POST data

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I'm trying to catch the POST requests made after logging into a website using Firefox Developer Tools, but as soon as the page loads and redirects me to the logged in page, all the entries in 'Network' section are overwritten with GET requests made to the logged in page and the POST are lost. How can I access the POST requests?

Comment: you can't use the Network table to measure POST on most sites, because as you said, the page immediately redirects as soon as the 201 response is recieved. I'd recommend using a tool like Fiddler which presents activity as a log so you can look at stuff that has already happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the "Settings" panel of the Developer Tools and under "Common Preferences", select "Enable persistent logs".